# Dynamic Dispatch in .Net Standard 1.4

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I've used dynamic dispatch in .Net to do things like eventsourcing in the past. You can see the approach in for e.g. [this article from 2009](http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/11/02/Event-Sourcing-and-CQRS-Lets-use-it)

In short, you have a base Event type

```
public class Event {}
```

and specific Events

```
public class QuestionAsked : Event {}
public class QuestionAnswered : Event {}
```

Some other class can just take an enumerable of `Event` to apply them

```
// snip

public void Apply(IEnumerable<Event> events) => events.ToList().ForEach(Apply);

public void Apply(Event ev) => ((dynamic) this).Apply((dynamic) ev);

private void Apply(QuestionAnswered qa) {
 //something
}
// end snip
```

This class doesn't need to have an `Apply` method for each type. It just ignores any events it doesn't care about.

I've just tried to do the same thing using .NetStandard 1.4 and if I try to apply a type for which there isn't a private `Apply` method I get a `StackOverflowException`

Has dynamic dispatch changed between .Net 4.5.x and .Net (Core|Standard)? Can I no longer use this method?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use the .NET standard library form a .NET Framework or .NET Core host application? The stack overflow is certainly from Apply calling itself during dynamic dispatch

Comment: I'm wondering how this has ever **not** thrown a StackOverflowException for unknown events..

Comment: I'll work up a .Net 4.5.x example... I would have been 100% certain that it works if it hadn't not worked here. :)

Comment: Yep, just made a .Net 4.5 example... and... it doesn't work :/ Goodness knows what code I've mixed up in my head that did work with this code which doesn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one drawback of learning in the open is that sometimes you learn you're wrong :)

I tried the same code in .Net 4.5.x and it fails too - I'm clearly conflating something safe I've used in the past with this unsafe code.

It was really just a terse expression of `if there is a method called Apply that takes this type as an argument then invoke it` so...

```
public void Apply(IEnumerable<Event> events) => events.ToList().ForEach(Apply);

public void Apply(Event ev)
{
    GetType()
        .GetRuntimeMethods()
        .Where(mi => mi.IsPrivate)
        .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Apply")
        .Where(mi => mi.GetParameters().Length == 1)
        .SingleOrDefault(mi => mi.GetParameters().SingleOrDefault()?.ParameterType == ev.GetType())
        ?.Invoke(this, new[] {ev});
}
```

My tests pass with that code. I.e. events that have a method are applied and events that do not are ignored.

Obviously in a *real* application you only need to find the methods once and then check them with each call but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader ;P